# How to stop a running PING in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've been given a task to ping two sites in a whole day, so I created a function with two functions in it, the inside is ping1() and ping2(). When the ping1() runs, after 5minutes it should run the next ping2()
But my problem is, it is not proceeding to the next function.
I tried this code:

```
def run():

    start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
    tenmins_add = datetime.timedelta(seconds = 5)
    add = start_time + tenmins_add

    print(start_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    print(add.strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    def ping1():
        os.system("echo START PING 1 " + str(start_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "!~")
        os.system("ping www.google.com")
        os.system("echo PING 1")

    def ping2():
        os.system("echo START PING 2 " + str(start_time.strftime("%H:%M:%S")) + "!~")
        os.system("ping www.facebook.com")
        os.system("echo END OF PING 2")

    ping1()
    ping2()

while True:
    os.system("clear")
    run()
    if datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S") == add.strftime("%H:%M:%S"):
        ping1().terminate()
    else:
        pass
```

I don't know what part is wrong in my code.

Comment: you need to use threading

Answer (score 1):

The code will get stuck on `os.system("ping www.google.com")`

what you need to do is `os.system("ping -i 1 -c 10 www.google.com")`

`-i` sets the interval between each ping

`-c` sets the number of pings

So the given examples runs for 10 secs and then moves to the next line of code